# jquery ui dialog close button direction

Tags: css, jquery-ui

Is it possible to change the direction of the close button on the dialog,
Instead of the button will appear on the right side dialog it will appear on  the left side of the dialog?
thanks,
mati

Comment: I would have thought this would be as simple as changing the relevant css within jquery-ui.css to float: left;

Comment: You could, but you will confuse the majority of users who will expect it to be top-right in common with pretty much every app/browser on the web.

Comment: hi thank you on your comment , which class should i have to change, becuse I tried to chane class on the button and it's didnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
position: absolute;
left: .3em;
top: 50%;
width: 20px;
margin: -10px 0 0 0;
padding: 1px;
height: 20px;
}
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-title {
float: right;
margin: .1em 0;
white-space: nowrap;
width: 87%;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```